# Cannot load image from file name using method Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filename);

Tags: java, javax.imageio, toolkit

I have problem to load image by file name by using method Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filename); MediaTracker return false which means there is no image loaded isn't? How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance. Below is my code:

```
String name = "example.jpg";
File inputFile = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name);
BufferedImage thumbImage = getThumbnail(name, 200, 120, 0, name);              
File outputfile = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + "2"+name);
ImageIO.write(thumbImage, "jpg", outputfile);
```

getThumbnail method :

```
private static BufferedImage getThumbnail(String filename, int thumbWidth, int thumbHeight, int quality, String outFileName)
throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {

//load image from filename
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filename);
MediaTracker mediaTracker = new MediaTracker(new Container());
mediaTracker.addImage(image, 0);
mediaTracker.waitForID(0);
 // use this to test for errors at this point: 
System.out.println(mediaTracker.isErrorAny());

//determine thumbnail size from WIDTH and HEIGHT
double thumbRatio = (double)thumbWidth / (double)thumbHeight;
int imageWidth = image.getWidth(null);
int imageHeight = image.getHeight(null);
double imageRatio = (double)imageWidth / (double) imageHeight;
if (thumbRatio < imageRatio){
    thumbHeight = (int)(thumbWidth / imageRatio);
    } else{
        thumbWidth = (int)(thumbHeight * imageRatio);
    }

//draw original image to thumbnail image object and
//scale it to the new size
BufferedImage thumbImage = new BufferedImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D graphics2D = thumbImage.createGraphics();
graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight, null);

//save thumbnail image to outFileName
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFileName));
JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(thumbImage);
quality = Math.max(0, Math.min(quality, 100));
param.setQuality((float)quality / 100.0f, false);
encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);
encoder.encode(thumbImage);
out.close();

return thumbImage;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't

`BufferedImage thumbImage = getThumbnail(name, 200, 120, 0, name);`

be

`BufferedImage thumbImage = getThumbnail(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name, 200, 120, 0, name);`

?

Answer (score 0):

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(URL or file path);
```

The Toolkit is a class in the java.awt package that provides various resources and tools for the display system. One of the Toolkit methods is `getImage()` that functions much like the `getImage()` method in the Applet class. It is overloaded to take either a String filename parameter specifying the location of the image file or a URL parameter identifying the image file.

Before calling getImage(), one must have a reference to the Toolkit instance in use. The static method `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()` returns a reference to that Toolkit.

Comment: Oh, thanks @brijesh k. so my problem now because i didn't specify the directory that is why the image cannot be loaded :)